# combobox items appear outside combobox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I think the following picture describes the problem well enough.

[image: http://www.webeasy.com.gr/problem.jpg]

In my windows phone 7 application (C#), I have a combobox that binds some data (StatusNameAsceding, StatusNameDesceding etc)

As you can see the dropdown seems completely blank and its items appear over the dropdown except the selected one.
Any Idea.

**UPDATE...**
The code i use

for combobox... (xaml page)

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="OnSortingColumnChanged"
x:Name="SortingColumn" Margin="2,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"
VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0">
```

in App.xaml.cs

```
public enum SortingColumns
{
    StatusNameAscending = 0,
    StatusNameDescending,
    EXAMINOAscending,
    EXAMINODescending,
}
public SortingColumns SortingColumn { get; set; }
```

in back code (page.xaml.cs)

```
this.DataContext = CreateSampleData();

App.Current.SortingColumn = App.SortingColumns.StatusNameAscending;
SortingColumn.Items.Add(App.SortingColumns.StatusNameAscending.ToString());
SortingColumn.Items.Add(App.SortingColumns.StatusNameDescending.ToString());
SortingColumn.Items.Add(App.SortingColumns.EXAMINOAscending.ToString());
SortingColumn.Items.Add(App.SortingColumns.EXAMINODescending.ToString());
SortingColumn.SelectedIndex = (int)App.Current.SortingColumn;
```

and...

```
private void OnSortingColumnChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.SortingColumn = (App.SortingColumns)SortingColumn.SelectedIndex;

    // Rebind
    // The List control binds the data again when a different datacontext is set.
    var datacontext = DataContext;
    DataContext = null;
    DataContext = datacontext;
}
```

**UPDATE2...**
When I click in the blank list the selection change happens and the sorting applied
I think something wrong happens in combobox template, but I don't know what!
Any Idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Steve! You are very kind!

Comment: Can you post some code so we can understand what's going on?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used listpicker instead of combobox

```
<toolkit:ListPicker SelectionChanged="OnSortingColumnChanged" x:Name="SortingColumn" Margin="2,0,0,0" Foreground="Black" Width="300" Height="180" FontSize="18"></toolkit:ListPicker>
```

A few details...

First of all you must install Silverlight tool for Windows Phone. You can download it here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550

Then we go to AnyPage.xaml and built a sample User Interface but after that we declare like so:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

The rest of the code remains the same. For more information about listpicker take a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f397b9/using-listpicker-in-windows-phone-7/)